# Why RTCMultiConnection Event Type is always 'local'?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webrtc, phonegap, rtcmulticonnection

I'm trying to create a basic video chat using `RTCMultiConnection` `Webrtc`.

The code works fine in Safari browser but it always fails to show the joiners videos in a simple ios phonegap app. *so basically no one can see others videos.*

I added *iosrtc* plugin to my app as well...

Spent days trying to find the issue and I think I am getting close.

I found out that the `event.type` is always `local` for everyone.

So, the `event.type` is never `remote` for anyone that uses the app.

But when i test the same code in safari browser, the first joiner `event.type` is `local` and the rest of the joiners `event.type` is `remote` and thats why it works fine in the browser.

Now that I found the issue (sort of), I need to know why this is happening in the phonegap app and how to eradicate it.

This is my entire code, you can run this code directly in your browser as is and it will work fine:

**Javascript:**

```
// ......................................................
// .......................UI Code........................
// ......................................................
document.getElementById('open-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.open(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomOpened, roomid, error) {
        if(isRoomOpened === true) {
          showRoomURL(connection.sessionid);
        }
        else {
          disableInputButtons(true);
          if(error === 'Room not available') {
            alert('Someone already created this room. Please either join or create a separate room.');
            return;
          }
          alert(error);
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.join(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isJoinedRoom, roomid, error) {
      if (error) {
            disableInputButtons(true);
            if(error === 'Room not available') {
              alert('This room does not exist. Please either create it or wait for moderator to enter in the room.');
              return;
            }
            alert(error);
        }
    });
};
document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').onclick = function() {
    disableInputButtons();
    connection.openOrJoin(document.getElementById('room-id').value, function(isRoomExist, roomid, error) {
        if(error) {
          disableInputButtons(true);
          alert(error);
        }
        else if (connection.isInitiator === true) {
            // if room doesn't exist, it means that current user will create the room
            showRoomURL(roomid);
        }
    });
};
// ......................................................
// ..................RTCMultiConnection Code.............
// ......................................................
var connection = new RTCMultiConnection();
// by default, socket.io server is assumed to be deployed on your own URL
//connection.socketURL = '/';
// comment-out below line if you do not have your own socket.io server
connection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
connection.socketMessageEvent = 'video-conference-demo';
connection.session = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};
connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
    OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
    OfferToReceiveVideo: true
};
connection.videosContainer = document.getElementById('videos-container');



connection.onstream = function(event) {

var video = document.createElement('video');    


    if(event.type === 'local') {

    video.setAttribute('class', 'myvideo');
    //$('.yourVideo').attr('src', event.stream);
    //$('.yourVideo').attr('id', event.streamid);

    //alert('local');
      /*video.volume = 0;
      try {
          video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('muted'));
      } catch (e) {
          video.setAttribute('muted', true);

      }*/
    }


    if (event.type === 'remote') {
    alert('remote');

        video.setAttribute('class', 'othersvideo');
    } 

    //video.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);



    setTimeout(function() {


   var existing = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
    if(existing && existing.parentNode) {
      existing.parentNode.removeChild(existing);
    }

    event.mediaElement.removeAttribute('src');
    event.mediaElement.removeAttribute('srcObject');
    event.mediaElement.muted = true;
    event.mediaElement.volume = 0;



   try {
        video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('autoplay'));
        video.setAttributeNode(document.createAttribute('playsinline'));
    } catch (e) {
        video.setAttribute('autoplay', true);
        video.setAttribute('playsinline', true);

    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(event)); 


   video.srcObject = event.stream;
    var width = parseInt(connection.videosContainer.clientWidth / 3) - 20;
    var width = $(document).width();
    var height = $(document).height();
    var mediaElement = getHTMLMediaElement(video, {
        /*title: event.userid,*/
        buttons: ['full-screen'],
        width: width,
        showOnMouseEnter: false
    });


    connection.videosContainer.appendChild(mediaElement);   
    mediaElement.media.play();  


    var isInitiator = connection.isInitiator;

    if (isInitiator === true && event.type === 'local') {
        // initiator's own stream
    alert('you are initiator');
    }else{
    alert('you are remote');
    }

    mediaElement.id = event.streamid;


    //video.play(); 
    }, 5000);









};
var recordingStatus = document.getElementById('recording-status');
var chkRecordConference = document.getElementById('record-entire-conference');
var btnStopRecording = document.getElementById('btn-stop-recording');
btnStopRecording.onclick = function() {
  var recorder = connection.recorder;
  if(!recorder) return alert('No recorder found.');
  recorder.stopRecording(function() {
    var blob = recorder.getBlob();
    invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
    connection.recorder = null;
    btnStopRecording.style.display = 'none';
    recordingStatus.style.display = 'none';
    chkRecordConference.parentNode.style.display = 'inline-block';
  });
};
connection.onstreamended = function(event) {
    var mediaElement = document.getElementById(event.streamid);
    if (mediaElement) {
        mediaElement.parentNode.removeChild(mediaElement);
    }
};
connection.onMediaError = function(e) {
    if (e.message === 'Concurrent mic process limit.') {
        if (DetectRTC.audioInputDevices.length <= 1) {
            alert('Please select external microphone. Check github issue number 483.');
            return;
        }
        var secondaryMic = DetectRTC.audioInputDevices[1].deviceId;
        connection.mediaConstraints.audio = {
            deviceId: secondaryMic
        };
        connection.join(connection.sessionid);
    }
};
// ..................................
// ALL below scripts are redundant!!!
// ..................................
function disableInputButtons(enable) {
    document.getElementById('room-id').onkeyup();
    document.getElementById('open-or-join-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('open-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('join-room').disabled = !enable;
    document.getElementById('room-id').disabled = !enable;
}
// ......................................................
// ......................Handling Room-ID................
// ......................................................
function showRoomURL(roomid) {
    var roomHashURL = '#' + roomid;
    var roomQueryStringURL = '?roomid=' + roomid;
    var html = '<h2>Unique URL for your room:</h2><br>';
    html += 'Hash URL: <a href="' + roomHashURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomHashURL + '</a>';
    html += '<br>';
    html += 'QueryString URL: <a href="' + roomQueryStringURL + '" target="_blank">' + roomQueryStringURL + '</a>';
    var roomURLsDiv = document.getElementById('room-urls');
    roomURLsDiv.innerHTML = html;
    roomURLsDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
(function() {
    var params = {},
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
    function d(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
    var match, search = window.location.search;
    while (match = r.exec(search.substring(1)))
        params[d(match[1])] = d(match[2]);
    window.params = params;
})();
var roomid = '';
if (localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent)) {
    roomid = localStorage.getItem(connection.socketMessageEvent);
} else {
    roomid = connection.token();
}
var txtRoomId = document.getElementById('room-id');
txtRoomId.value = roomid;
txtRoomId.onkeyup = txtRoomId.oninput = txtRoomId.onpaste = function() {
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, document.getElementById('room-id').value);
};
var hashString = location.hash.replace('#', '');
if (hashString.length && hashString.indexOf('comment-') == 0) {
    hashString = '';
}
var roomid = params.roomid;
if (!roomid && hashString.length) {
    roomid = hashString;
}
if (roomid && roomid.length) {
    document.getElementById('room-id').value = roomid;
    localStorage.setItem(connection.socketMessageEvent, roomid);
    // auto-join-room
    (function reCheckRoomPresence() {
        connection.checkPresence(roomid, function(isRoomExist) {
            if (isRoomExist) {
                connection.join(roomid);
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(reCheckRoomPresence, 5000);
        });
    })();
    disableInputButtons();
}
// detect 2G
if(navigator.connection &&
   navigator.connection.type === 'cellular' &&
   navigator.connection.downlinkMax <= 0.115) {
  alert('2G is not supported. Please use a better internet service.');
}


$(document).on('click', '.mybtn', function() {
 window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(" https://vps267717.ovh.net/webrtc", "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=yes");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Demo version: 2019.01.09 -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Video Conferencing using RTCMultiConnection</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">


  <script>
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();


}, 4000);

// alert dialog dismissed
function alertDismissed() {

}
</script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/stylesheet.css">
  <script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/menu.js"></script>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  


<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dist/RTCMultiConnection.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js"></script>
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<!-- custom layout for HTML5 audio/video elements -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dev/getHTMLMediaElement.css">
<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/dev/getHTMLMediaElement.js"></script>

<script src="https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/node_modules/recordrtc/RecordRTC.js"></script>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="ios-websocket-hack.js"></script>

  <style>
 /* .myvideo{
  width:100px !important;
  height:100px !important;
   background:#ccc;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:10;

  }

  .othersvideo{
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
   background:#ccc;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:0;
  }*/


          * {
            word-wrap:break-word;
        }
        video {
            object-fit: fill;
            width: 30%;
        }
        button,
        input,
        select {
            font-weight: normal;
            padding: 2px 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            text-shadow: none;
            font-size: 16px;
            outline: none;
        }
        .make-center {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        img, input, textarea {
          max-width: 100%
        }
        @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
            .fork-left, .fork-right, .github-stargazers {
                display: none;
            }
        }
  </style>


</head>
<body>


<button class="mybtn" >click me now</button>

  <section class="make-center">
    <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" id="record-entire-conference"> Record Entire Conference In The Browser?</label>
      <span id="recording-status" style="display: none;"></span>
      <button id="btn-stop-recording" style="display: none;">Stop Recording</button>
      <br><br>

      <input type="text" id="room-id" value="abcdef" autocorrect=off autocapitalize=off size=20>
      <button id="open-room">Open Room</button>
      <button id="join-room">Join Room</button>
      <button id="open-or-join-room">Auto Open Or Join Room</button>

    </div>

    <div id="videos-container" style="margin: 20px 0;"></div>

    <div id="room-urls" style="text-align: center;display: none;background: #F1EDED;margin: 15px -10px;border: 1px solid rgb(189, 189, 189);border-left: 0;border-right: 0;"></div>
  </section>






 <script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue

Comment: @G-Man, i never did. I gave up...

Comment: I disabled all adapterjs code (enableAdapter = false) in the RTCMulticonnection js file then it started working. I kind of gave up on this library it has too many references to document, too many things that i don't need, which makes it hard to migrate to things like react native for example. Now I am writing my own library and it is going well

Comment: @G-Man, thanks for the tip. I would love to try out your library when its done. keep us posted.